# Why is my data populating twice in the tables but it is only stored once in the database?

Tags: php, html, sql, loops, while-loop

So my table is showing the same line of data twice. However in the database it is only stored once. I think there may be an issue with the while loop. I am inserting data to the database which is storing fine in the database however when i am printing that to the screen it repeats the same value twice.

```
<?php
include ("dbConnect.php");

$query = $db->prepare("select * from tasks LEFT JOIN challenge ON tasks.task = challenge.challenge where start_date <= NOW() and end_date >= NOW() ORDER BY challenge.achievement DESC limit 8");
$query->execute();
// Display search result
         if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {

                echo "<table id=\"example\" style=\"font-family:arial;color:#ffffff;\" class=\"table table-striped table-bordered\" style=\"width:100%\">"; 
                echo "<thead><tr>
                <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Customer ID</th>
                <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Name</th>                
                <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Score</th>
                <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Challenge</th>
                <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Rank</th>
            </tr></thead><tbody>";
            $position = 1; 
            while ($results = $query->fetch()) {


                $count = count($results);

                echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";            
                echo $results['cust_id'];
                echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
                echo $results['forename'];
                echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
                echo $results['achievement'];
                echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
                echo $results['challenge'];
                echo "<td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
                echo "Position: $position";
                $position = $position+1;

                } 
}       

                echo '</td></tr></tbody>';              

                echo "</table>";            

?>
```

Comment: You should first verify that your query returns the rows you expect.

Comment: Without knowing what the schemas are for your tables, you can try DISTINCT/GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your missing your closing td and tr within your loop. But on your query using the LEFT JOIN you will get as many tasks per challenge. So if you task 1 has 2 challenges than it will display task 1, 2 times. 1 for each challenge. Hope this helps.
Below I just moved your close TD TR into the loop.

```
 <?php
include ("dbConnect.php");

$query = $db->prepare("select * from tasks LEFT JOIN challenge ON tasks.task = challenge.challenge where start_date <= NOW() and end_date >= NOW() ORDER BY challenge.achievement DESC limit 8");
$query->execute();
// Display search result
         if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {

                echo "<table id=\"example\" style=\"font-family:arial;color:#ffffff;\" class=\"table table-striped table-bordered\" style=\"width:100%\">"; 
                echo "<thead><tr>
                <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Customer ID</th>
                <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Name</th>                
                <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Score</th>
                <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Challenge</th>
                <th style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:3px;border-color:#575757;background:#575757;\">Rank</th>
            </tr></thead><tbody>";
            $position = 1; 
            while ($results = $query->fetch()) {


                $count = count($results);

                echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";            
                echo $results['cust_id'];
                echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
                echo $results['forename'];
                echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
                echo $results['achievement'];
                echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
                echo $results['challenge'];
                echo "<td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#D3D3D3;\">";
                echo "Position: $position";
                $position = $position+1;
                echo '</td></tr></tbody>';              
                } 
}       
            echo '</tbody>';              
            echo "</table>";            

?>
```

Comment: Justin thank you! I had two tasks set to the same value

Answer (score 0):

**tasks LEFT JOIN challenge ON tasks.task = challenge.challenge**
You are doing a left join first confirm you don't have **multiple entries of same primary-key** in your relation table.

Answer (score -2):

Use `fetchAll()`, and a `foreach`:

```
$results = $query->fetchAll();

foreach ($results as $result) {
 //etc
}
```